# Buffering of http requests to Bluemix App

Tags: http, ibm-cloud, buffering

I have an application on Bluemix written on Golang. I send to it a large chunked HTTP request and I see that my application gets a notice that it got this request only when the request fully reaches the destination instead of starting after the header appeared (in the beginning without waiting to the body).

The same code on regular server works fine without any delays, the problem seems to be only when it runs on Bluemix. I did several experiments, like listening to tcp instead of http (but still sending http requests), and again the first notice that there is some networking only when the request fully arrived. I also tried to stream the data very slowly, 1 byte in 100ms, and send small requests, and the result is the same.

I assume there is some buffering before redirecting the request to the dynamic port the App has, or maybe in some other place. Any help why does it happen and how to avoid it, will be very appreciated. Thank you.

UPD: Server code in Go that listens to TCP:

```
func main() {
    var port string
    if port = os.Getenv("PORT"); len(port) == 0 { port = DEFAULT_PORT }
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":"+port)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listening:", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    // Close the listener when the application closes.
    defer l.Close()
    for {
        // Listen for an incoming connection.
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting: ", err.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        // Handle connections in a new goroutine.
        go handleTCPRequest(conn)
    }
}

func handleTCPRequest(conn net.Conn) {
    fmt.Println("Got something!!!", conn)
    // Make a buffer to hold incoming data.
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    // Read the incoming connection into the buffer.
    reqLen, err := conn.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading:", err.Error(), conn)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Read: ", reqLen, buf, conn)
    }
    // Close the connection when you're done with it.
    conn.Close()
}
```

The client just sends a big http request or a throttled one.
I would expect to get print "Got Something" really fast, after first packages arrive, but this is not what I see. For example for a throttling client I will get all the package together and print "Got something" only after the full package arrives.

Code of throttling client in Go:

```
reader, writer := io.Pipe()
request, _ := http.NewRequest("PUT", URL, reader)
request.Header = http.Header{}
request.Header["Connection"]=[]string {"keep-alive"}
request.Header["X-Content-Type-Options"]=[]string {"nosniff"}
request.Header["Accept-Encoding"]=[]string{"gzip, deflate"}
request.Header["Accept"]=[]string{"*/*"}
request.Header["Transfer-Encoding"]=[]string {"chunked"}
request.TransferEncoding=[]string {"chunked"}

//puts one byte in 100ms asynchronously
go func(w *io.PipeWriter){
    i:=0
    for true {
        i+=1
        w.Write([]byte{0})
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Print("-")
        if i > 1000 {
            w.CloseWithError(io.EOF)
            break
        }
    }
}(writer)

http.DefaultClient.Do(request)
```

Comment: It would help if you could add your code here, so someone can comment on it.

Comment: Hi @AlexdaSilva, I added an example of one of the tests, hope it is clear enough. Will very appreciate your help.